# Assigning same data to two different variable updates both of variables + Angular 6

Tags: angular, filter

I want to do search on the data at client side for that i need to set response of API in two different variables

code is as below.

```
public masterData:any = [];
public searchData:any = [];
this.httpClient.post("url", {id:'1'}).subscribe((res:any)=>{
  if(res.success){
    this.masterData = res.data;
    this.searchData = res.data;
  }
})
```

when I search and set my searchData variable in that case it also update the **masterData** as well

so I dont want to update that ..

I always want to search on **masterData** and set in **searchData**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the spread operator :

```
this.masterData = [ ...res.data ];
this.searchData = [ ...res.data ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash because it does a deep clone of the object. And it's the more perfect way of cloning an object. **Spread operator** and **Object.assign** does not do that.

The function is `_.cloneDeep(obj2)`

> Here is an example:

```
var obj1 = _.cloneDeep(obj2);
```

Still, if you want to use the `Spread operator` or `Object.assign`, then here is an example.

```
var obj1 = [ ...obj2 ];
var obj1 = Object.assign(obj2);
```

Comment: The data isn't objects, using lodash implies a new dependency, and nothing states that he wants separate references on array items (maybe he want two distinct datasources, but both have the same object references).

Comment: @trichetriche Agree with you about the lodash fact. But also one fact, in Javascript array is also an object. And cloneDeep work on both object and array.

Comment: This worked for my scenario, Thanks @Surjeet Bhadauriya.